# Trouble with using .substr() and getting int values

Tags: c++, string, char

Yes, this is a school project, and yes, I'm hopelessly stuck again.  The professor is demanding the use of .substr() in this project, and I'm unsure how exactly to deal with this.  I've tried numerous ways of converting a single character string to a char but c++ is fighting me the whole way.  My code:

```
 int shift;
 std::string tChar;
 std::cout << "Enter text to be encrypted.\n";

 getline(std::cin, plainText);

 char myChar;

 for (int x = 0; x < plainText.length(); x++)
 {
     tChar = plainText.substr(x,1);

 }
```

How in the world do I get the single character tChar string turned into a char that I can get an integer value out of, or better yet, just add another integer to.  Supposed to be building a simply Caesar Cipher, but I have absolutely no clue on how to turn a string into a single char.

Comment: DONT use substr to extract char, use at()

Comment: or even just regular `operator[]` if you don't care about bound checking.

Comment: There has to be a better intended use of `substr` in the program than here.

Comment: I've never worked with substr before, and after looking at the documentation, it seemed like this was the only way to use it to accomplish my task.  I very well could be way off base in its usage and welcome any input on how I should be implementing it.

Comment: `x` should go to `plainText.length()-1`

Comment: @kefkamaydie Assuming you really must use `substr` for this: Aren't you almost there? `tChar[0]` is the character you are looking for. You can assign that to a `char` if you want.

Comment: @borisbn It does that already: `x < plainText.length()`.

Comment: Uuuups. Beg your pardon. /me should sleep))

Answer (score 0):

try

```
int shift;
char tChar;
std::cout << "Enter text to be encrypted.\n";
getline(std::cin, plainText);
char myChar;
for (int x = 0; x < plainText.length(); x++)
{
   tChar = plainText[x];
}
```

Comment: Problem is is that I must use substr somewhere in the program.  Is it possible to build a string from a char array using substr?

Comment: you can build a string from a char array by providing the constructor pointers to the first index and one past the last index. don't quite see what you're driving at with your substr usage requirement ?

Comment: I have to use it somewhere, so if I don't use it during the encrypting, I'd be forced to use it during decrypting.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm maybe your professor wants you to use the substr inorder to get the words in the text which needs to be ciphered.

So a sample pseudo code will be:

```
for( int i = 0;  i < plaintext.length(); i++ )
{
    int aStart = i;
    // iterate till you reach a space
    while( i < plainText.length() && plainText[ i ] != ' ' ) i++;
    // get the word using substr
    std::string aTempString = plainText.substr( aStart, (i - aStart) - 1 );  // (i - aStart) - 1 will give you the length of the word
    // perform ciphering
    encryptMe( aTempString );
}
```

Hope this helps.